# How do I prevent the Camel properties listener from trying to replace a string in route containing "{{"?

Tags: apache-camel, spring-camel

I am trying to connect to an sftp the password for which contains "{{". This results in the Camel properties listener trying to find a property with a key that contains part of the password after the "{{". This fails. How can I prevent this problem? I have tried escaping the "{{" characters manually with and without using RAW in the url. I've also tried using the endpoint dsl.

Also, I need to pull the password from a Spring properties file initially, like

spring.my.password=....{{...

Answer (score 0):

As usually, Camel has the answer !
Just enclose the original password into the RAW function, ie:

```
"...?password=RAW("+pwd+")
```

More info at:
https://camel.apache.org/manual/faq/how-do-i-configure-password-options-on-camel-endpoints-without-the-value-being-encoded.html